Google Pixel with Android 15 Beta, can't unlock bootloader
I have a Pixel 7 Pro that is enrolled into the Adroid 15 beta program, and in developer options, "OEM unlocking" is greyed out so I can't unlock the bootloader.
Is there a way around this?

(Self answering so someone might find the answer to their problem)
Unfortunately some phones have the OEM unlocking blocked by the provider (Verizon is an example I have seen), and I am unaware of any way to deal with this.
In my precise case, the phone I bought was enrolled in the Android 15 beta program. Unenrolling from this program (i.e. rolling back to the latest stable Android 14 version) brought the OEM unlocking option back.
To unenrol, make sure you are logged into a google account on the phone, then go to Android Beta (g.co/androidbeta), sign in with the same account. It should show the phone as listed with the account, and somewhere will be the option to unenrol.
When you unenrol, it will push an update to your phone within the next 24 hours. You might have to manually go to updates in Settings. Running the update to roll back will completely wipe your phone.
After the update and stepping through the setup process, OEM unlocking should now be available.
